# Can the Lenovo Thinkvantage button be disabled to avoid the need for a custom Thinkpad MBR?

Tags: thinkpad, bootloader, mbr

I've migrated to an SSD, but no MBR magic I try works to bootup WinXP from my Lenovo T500. The problem seems to be that a Lenovo laptop requires a custom MBR to provide functionality from the ThinkVantage button.

Instead of using the Lenovo recovery disks to reformat my SSD with a custom MBR, can I simply turn off the need for a custom MBR on the laptop?

Is it possible to undo whatever bios hook requires a Lenovo MBR?

Comment: I'm confused...you can put any MBR on it that you want, as long as you don't mind the ThinkVantage button not working between the BIOS and the operating system.

Comment: I've tried that, and still encounter a cannot load system error. I also can't seem to fix the MBR using the recovery console either (XP sp3 just goes straight to the partition delete/create screen). I've been using HBCD to get into the system: http://superuser.com/questions/476928/how-can-i-duplicate-hbcds-xp-boot-loader-with-my-mbr
Is it possible to diagnose why my on-disk MBR can't find the system partition? It feels like normal MBR operation and recovery is being circumvented somehow.

Comment: I've never tried changing one on-the-fly on these (or I'd have made an answer with those details), but I can certainly say that clean non-Lenovo installations work just fine, so it's doable in some capacity.